# Getting error "Process unexpectedly exit" in Android Studio 4.0.1

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am trying to build APK in andorid studio with `classpath:'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'`. but i'm getting error 'Process unexpectedly exit'. I also downgrade gradle version but nothing works. Please help to solve this problem, Thanks in advance.

Please also check ionic error as below screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM0y1.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUfE8.png

Comment: just try downgrading to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'

Comment: I already tried this solution

Comment: have you add in `build.gradle(:app):` this==> `android {
    configurations.matching { it.name == '_internal_aapt2_binary' }.all { config ->
            config.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                details.useVersion("3.3.2-5309881")
            }}
}`

Comment: Yes, also tried this solution. It gives error:

Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.file.ProjectLayout.directoryProperty(Lorg/gradle/api/provider/Provider;)Lorg/gradle/api/file/DirectoryProperty;'.